# issue with sending data using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having this annoying problem here with `$.ajax()...` in the PHP code. I can't retrieve the data sent by `ajax` function.

```
<?php


if ($_POST){
    include 'Bdd_connexion.php';

    $filiere = $_POST['filiere'];
    /*$annee = $_POST['annee'];
    $groupe = $_POST['groupe'];*/

    $sql = "";
    $query = $Conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Etudiant` WHERE `filiere` = '".$filiere."'");
    $result = $query->execute();
        if ($result)
            echo "success";

    $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        foreach($results as $rows)
            echo $rows['Nom'];  

}else{

    echo "No post";
}?>
```

```
<head>
    <title> La liste des presences </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Liste_des_presences_css.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var filiere; var annee; var groupe;
    fil = false;
    ann = false;
    grp = false; 


        function getEventTarget(e) {
                  e = e || window.event;
                    return e.target || e.srcElement; 
                }

        function clickFil(event) {
            var target = getEventTarget(event);
            if(target.innerHTML != "Selectionner un choix"){
                filiere = target.innerHTML;
                fil = true;
                return true;
            }else{
            fil = false;
            return false;
                }
            };

            function clickAn(event) {
            var target = getEventTarget(event);
            if(target.innerHTML != "Selectionner un choix"){
                annee = target.innerHTML;
                ann = true;
                return true;
            }else{
            ann = false;
            return false;
                }
            };

            function clickGrp(event) {
            var target = getEventTarget(event);
            if(target.innerHTML != "Selectionner un choix"){
                groupe = target.innerHTML;
                grp = true;
                return true;
            }else{
            grp = false;
            return false;
                }
            };

            function TestEntries(){
                if (!fil || !ann || !grp)
                    alert("Selectionner tout les champs !");
            }

            function ajax(event) {
            if ('preventDefault' in event) event.preventDefault();
                event.returnValue = false;

            $.ajax({

            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProjetWeb/Liste_des_presences.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { filiere : filiere 
                , groupe : groupe
                , annee : annee}, 
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            cache : false,

                });         

            }

    </script>
</head>

    <body>

<div class="container size" style="margin-top:40px">

          <div class="panel-body">

            <form action="Liste_des_presences.php" class="form-group" method="POST">

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                    </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="btn-group division11">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Filiere <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" onclick="clickFil(event);">
                                   <li><a value="select">Selectionner un choix</a></li>
                                   <li><a value="IL">IL</a></li>
                                   <li><a value="RSD">RSD</a></li>
                                   <li><a value="SSI">SSI</a></li>
                                   <li class="divider"></li>
                                   <li><a value="SII">SII</a></li>
                                   <li><a value="APCI">APCI</a></li>
                                   <li><a value="MIND">MIND</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                            </div>


                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg division3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Annee <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" onclick="clickAn(event);">
                                   <li><a>Selectionner un choix</a></li>
                                   <li><a>1</a></li>
                                   <li><a>2</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg division4">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Groupe <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" onclick="clickGrp(event);">
                                   <li><a>Selectionner un choix</a></li>
                                   <li><a>1</a></li>
                                   <li><a>2</a></li>
                                   <li><a>3</a></li>
                                   <li><a>4</a></li>
                                   <li><a>5</a></li>
                                   <li><a>6</a></li>
                                   <li><a>7</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                        </div>          
                        <center>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg padd">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Confirmer" onclick="TestEntries();" onfocus="ajax(event);"/>
                            </div>
                        </center>   

                        </div>

                        <form  action="" class="form-group" method="POST">
                            <div><hr/></div>
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr> 
                                            <th>Nom</th>
                                            <th>Prenom</th>
                                            <th>Presence</th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                        if ($_POST) foreach($results as $rows){
                                            echo '<tr>';
                                                echo '<td>'. $rows['Nom'].'</td>';
                                                echo '<td>'. $rows['Prenom'].'</td>';
                                                echo '<td></td>';
                                            echo '</tr>';
                                        }

                                    ?>
                                    </tbody>                                    
                                </table>



                          </form>

                    </form> 





                        </div>

                    </div>  


        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type=""></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type=""></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Please .. i'll appreciate any help ... thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by 'can't access the data in the php code.' Is it echoing 'no post?' btw, recommend using `is_empty($_POST)` rather than truthiness check. Have you set a breakpoint in your browsers debugger to ensure the ajax call is firing with the data you want?

Comment: Thanks for replying, look, i'm sending these three values (filiere,annee,groupe) using $.ajax() method ... in php code, i'm trying to get these values with $_POST in order to execute an update query ... but $_POST is not recieving anything ..

Comment: I'll restate the question a bit differently, __how__ do you know the $_POST array doesn't have what you want? Is there any error message in the webserver error logs like 'PHP Warning, undefined index 'filiere' in /var/www/yourscript.php LINE 4'? If the problem is that the DB isn't being update there are a million and a half possible explanations.

Comment: It gives me this:  Notice: Undefined index: filiere in C:\wamp\www\ProjetWeb\Liste_des_presences.php on line 9 ..

Comment: line 9 which is : $filiere = $_POST['filiere'];

Comment: inspect the actual request in browser console and see exactly what is sent. You haven't shown where you call any of your functions so we can't help a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that filiere actually has a value when passed through?

Comment: yes @haxtbh .. i've tried alert(filiere) .. and it shows me the value..

Comment: @charlietfl ... i've called ajax(event) when submitting the form .. (confirm button) ... the other functions like (clickfil or click grp) are called whenver i choose a value from the dropdown list of "filiere" or "groupe" or "annee" .... i can't display it here i do not know where is the problem .. maybe it is the main issue ..

Comment: Can you check the data being sent by the browser using the console too? Confirm all data is being sent as expected. Put an `isset` around the php var to test it too.

Comment: Why do you exec the ajax on the onfocus event too?? This may cause an issue if its firing before the data is populated.

Comment: @haxtbh .. the var is not being sent .. i've tested it by isset

Comment: Then most likely the ajax is being sent before the var gets populated. Which is why i asked why its being exec on the `onfocus` event.

Comment: much simpler to just use jQuery `serialize()` to set all the form data for the ajax request. Would remove all of your global variables and probably most of the other event handlers. You have some very strange form code and it is more complex than it needs to be

Answer (score -1):

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "count.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $(".deletefasl").html(html);
                        }
                    });
```

your data string should be

```
 var dataString = 'varibale='+ id;
```

or user $.post

```
$.post("filename.php", { var in php : var in jquery or javascript},
                         function(result){
}
});
```

Comment: Nothing is changed .. the same problem.